# How to generate a PEM file from an APNs certificate on MacOS

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, apple-push-notifications, pyapns

I am trying to use [PyAPNs2](https://github.com/Pr0Ger/PyAPNs2) on MacOS to send push notifications to iOS devices. The snippets for certificate-based authentication show that I evidently need a PEM file.

I followed [some](https://www.gfrigerio.com/apple-push-notifications/) [guides](https://michaelwashburnjr.com/blog/apple-push-notification-service-certificates) to download and install an APNs certificate with a `.cer` extension. However, after using Keychain Access to export the certificate in P12 format, I get errors when trying to convert the file to PEM format:

```
>> openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem -nodes -clcerts

Enter Import Password:
Error outputting keys and certificates
8060FBF201000000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:341:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```

One thing I have noted is that in the tutorials the exported P12 certificate is called `certificate.p12` while the file I have is called `Certificates.p12`. Maybe something changed recently which invalidated the command used in the tutorials.

How can I correctly convert the downloaded APNs certificate correctly to PEM format and use it with pyAPNs2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to add a `-legacy` flag for openssl.

Here is the command that worked for me:

`openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -out Certificates.pem -nodes -clcerts -legacy`